Removing a number from a string
There is a file with a list of numbers.
Example:
AK
  v       0.00o      0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00      43.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        585.00      43.00      -7.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
   -16611181.71     -90.16t     -7.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        585.00      57.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00      57.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00     100.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00     100.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      56.99       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        165.00      56.99      -7.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
   16612362.17     344.30t     -7.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        165.00      42.99       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      42.99       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00

This is what you should get after editing the file:
AK
  v       0.00o      0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00      43.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        585.00      43.00      -7.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00

        585.00      57.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00      57.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        750.00     100.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00     100.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      56.99       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
        165.00      56.99      -7.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
   
        165.00      42.99       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00      42.99       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
          0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00

You need to remove the entire line from it, where the number > 12000 or the number < -12000.
I tried to split the string into substrings and compare the value, but nothing worked :(
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

sg.theme('Default1')
OUTFILE = 'tmp.nc1'

layout = [
    [sg.InputText(), sg.FileBrowse('...', key = '-FILE-') ],
    [sg.Button('Исправить')]
]

window = sg.Window('Исправление позиций', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED: 
        break
    elif event == 'Исправить':
        with open(values['-FILE-']) as infile, open(OUTFILE, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                if line.startswith('   '):
                    str = line.split()
                    numbers = int(str[0])

                if not (numbers < 12000) or not (numbers > -12000):
                    outfile.write(line)
                
        os.remove(values['-FILE-'])
        os.rename(OUTFILE, values['-FILE-'])

window.close()


please post a reproducible code. In your code it's not clear what infile is.  Hardcode the values if it comes from a file, so the code can be run. I see some "numbers" that have characters attached to them. They will make your cast to int throw an exception that you should capture

looks like you could use pandas and apply some rules to filter the rows you don't need and clean data (like characters attached to numbers)

You say "where the number". Do you mean any number or just the first one? Also, do you intend to update the original file or create a new one?

If we ignore the irrelevant GUI parts of the OP and assume that the file needs to be modified in situ then:
def skip(t):
    try:
        x = float(t)
        if x < -12000 or x > 12000:
            return True
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return False

with open("foo.txt", "r+") as data:
    output = []
    for row in data:
        if not any(skip(t) for t in row.split()):
            output.append(row)
    data.seek(0)
    data.writelines(output)
    data.truncate()


This is working within the limited data set given...

variable str changed to stm
int changed to float to account for decimals
Print statements for testing

<-SNIP->
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('   '):
            stm = line.split()
            numbers = float(stm[0])
            print(numbers)
            if not (numbers < 12000) or not (numbers > -12000):
                print(line)

<-SNIP->

This will not work. You'll get a ValueError exception when to try to convert the 2nd token in the 2nd line ("0.00o")

@SIGHUP The scenario presented only involves looking at the first column of numbers, and only explicitly looking at lines that start with '    '.  Thus the line that starts with 'AK' (1st line) or includes 'v' (2nd line) are not processed (as per the original specification).

There is nothing in the question that explains your assertion

@SIGHUP, no, my assertion comes from the code posted.
